# Joining Tables for COUNT Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following script to display pages, where $URL matches a page URL (e.g. `MySite/People/Carl_Sagan`)...

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :url";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':url',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();

switch($Total['num'])
{
 case 1:
 break;
 case 2:
 break;
 default:
 break;
}
```

On another site, I want to join several tables together, forming sort of a mini-encyclopedia. I know how to use the `UNION` command, but it isn't working with this query. Note that the target field in the table gz_life is named Taxon, not URL. I thought I could somehow alias it - Taxon AS URL - but that doesn't seem to be working, either.

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :url
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :url
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :url";
```

Can anyone tell me the best way to join tables together in a PDO query?

Comment: we need further instructions...

Comment: Sorry, my question was somehow posted by mistake before I finished writing it. ;)

Comment: Be careful multiple `:url` works when `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` enabled. Default value is **True** on PHP 5.2 or later, but this option is frequently disabled for other reasons.

Comment: @ CertainN - Are you saying that, before I can union two or more tables on a common field (e.g. URL), I have to enable "PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES"? How do I enable it?

Comment: You would need to provide what the relational fields are which allow joining each table together. ie, how does pox_topics table relate to people table? or to gz_life etc.

Comment: The tables don't relate to each other at all. Let's start with my website URL:

http://MySite

Now, if I query (COUNT) the table people, I'll be able to display URL's like this:

http://MySite/Carl_Sagan

If I query the table pox_topics, I'll be able to display this URL:

http://MySite/Ecology

I want to be able to display BOTH. I'm combining several websites into a single mini-encyclopedia, kind of similar to Wikipedia.

Comment: I think I made a mistake by including the word "Joining" in the title. I should have used UNION instead. Technically, I'm not joining tables; rather, I'm simply counting the rows that match page URL's in multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this (if I understand what you're trying to achieve). One would be use what you already have, but do the last step to add up the counts:

```
SELECT SUM(num) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :url
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :url
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :url
) as subquery
```

Note that you will need the alias for the subquery to make the query correct.

Comment: Yes! That's very easy for me to understand. ;) However, I'm getting a syntax error that I haven't been able to fix yet. This is my current code, which I modified slightly from yours:

 $sql= "SELECT SUM(num) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :url
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :url
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :url;
)";

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(':url',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
 $Total = $stmt->fetch();

Comment: Now I'm getting the error message "Every derived table must have its own alias."

Comment: It looks like you left out the litte "x" that I put at the end. That's an alias for the subquery, which is required even though we're not using it for anything.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. What do you mean by "the alias" for the subquery? If I understand correctly, I should just replace "subquery" with an arbitrary name for the tables that are linked together. So I assigned it the name "Go," but it isn't working...

 $sql= "SELECT SUM(num) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :url
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :url
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :url
) as Go";

Comment: I just discovered that it doesn't work even if I strip it down to just one table query. So I must have made a mistake somewhere...

     $sql= "SELECT SUM(num) FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :url
    ) AS X";
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam(':url',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();
     $Total = $stmt->fetch();

    switch($Total['num'])
    // It returns a value of 0.

Comment: I tested my SQL as it appears in my answer (substituting a literal value for `:url`) and it is worked, so the problem must be in your PHP code. I can't really read your PHP code here in the comments, so it's hard for me to debug what you're writing here.

Comment: Or else the problem is that your URL string just doesn't match what's in the database? There are so many ways that this code could go wrong.

Comment: OK. If it works for you, then I'll  mark it as the correct answer and continue trying to debug it on my end. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you could live with the counts on one line, you could write a query that uses `:url` exactly once:

```
select tp.num_topic, tp.num_people, count(*) as num_taxon
from (select t.url, t.num_topic, count(*) as num_people
      from (SELECT t.url, COUNT(URL) AS num_topic
            from pox_topics t
            where t.URL = :url
           ) t join
           people p
           on t.url = p.url
    ) tp join
    gz_life gl
    on gl.Taxon = tp.url;
```

This turns the `:url` into a column and then uses successive layers of subqueries to calculate the counts.

EDIT:

It is possible that some of the counts would be 0.  To handle that situation:

```
select tp.num_topic, tp.num_people, count(gl.taxon) as num_taxon
from (select t.url, t.num_topic, count(p.url) as num_people
      from (SELECT const.url, COUNT(t.URL) AS num_topic
            from (select :url as url) const left outer join
                 pox_topics t
                 on t.url = const.url
           ) t left outer join
           people p
           on t.url = p.url
    ) tp left outer join
    gz_life gl
    on gl.Taxon = tp.url;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message that says "Column 'url' in field list is ambiguous." However, the error points to this line, which is a little confusing -  $stmt->execute();

Comment: I added table aliases to all the columns (good practice anyway).

Comment: Sorry, the revised code fixed the error - but it isn't displaying pages. I just get a 404 error; the result (or ($Total['num']) is 0. That's an impressive script, though.